# A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-polymer

```
DropdownButton(
                value: dropdownvalue,
                icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                items:items.map((String items) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: items,
                      child: Text(items)
                  );
                }
                ).toList(),
                onChanged: (Object? newValue) async {
                  setState(() {
                    dropdownvalue = newValue;
                  }
                  );
                },
              ),
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton/value.html), the field value for the DropDownButton widget is of type **final T?**. This means that it is a generic type that can also be nullable.

Since you did not provide a more inclusive example of your code, I am assuming from the error, that the variable ***dropdownvalue*** was declared of type String.

You can remedy the situation in this manner:

```
DropdownButton**<String>**(
                value: dropdownvalue,
                icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                items:items.map((String items) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: items,
                      child: Text(items)
                  );
                }
                ).toList(),
                onChanged: (**String** newValue) async {
                  setState(() {
                    dropdownvalue = newValue;
                  }
                  );
                },
              ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like that as specified in mooner's answer.

```
DropdownButton<String>(
  value: dropdownvalue,
  icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
  items: items.map((items) {
    return DropdownMenuItem(value: items, child: Text(items));
  }).toList(),
  onChanged: (newValue) {
    setState(() {
      dropdownvalue = newValue;
    });
  },
),
```

You don't need to specify type on items or newValue parameters. Also no need to use async keyword on onChanged function if you won't do any async operation.

Answer (score 0):

`DropdownButton` is a generic provide it with `T` like so `DropdownButton<String>` and then you can remove `Object?` and have `String?` instead, but it'll be inferred anyways now so you probably don't need to specify the type here.